# How do to fix foreach error in xml laravel 5.7

Tags: xml, laravel, laravel-5

I want to create a xml data in laravel 5.7 and i tested it using postman. For the data i am using json.

This is my data in json :

```
[
    {"fa_type_cd":"string","name":"Sting","user_value":"Sting","sort_seq":"1","type_cd":"string"},
    {"fa_type_cd":"string","name":"String","user_value":"String","sort_seq":"1","type_cd":"String"}
]
```

and this is my function in controller for create the xml :

```
public function createXml(Request $request){
    $data = $request->input('data');
    $decode_data = json_decode($data);

    $xmlrequest = '<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:c1c="http://splwg.com/C1CustomerContactMaintenance.xsd">
       <SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:wsse="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <wsse:Security>
            <wsse:UsernameToken>       
                <wsse:Username>Username</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="PasswordText">Password</wsse:Password>        
            </wsse:UsernameToken>    
        </wsse:Security>  
       </SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            <C1FieldActivityMaintenance dateTimeTagFormat="CdxDateTime"  transactionType ="UPDATE" >
                <C1FieldActivityMaintenanceService>
                    <C1FieldActivityMaintenanceHeader
                        FieldActivityID="111" 

                    /><C1FieldActivityMaintenanceDetails 
                        FieldActivityID="111" 
                        ActivityType="DE"  
                        > 
                        <FASteps>
                            <FAStepsHeader
                                FieldActivityID="111" 
                                />

                        </FASteps>
                        <FACharacteristics>
                            <FACharacteristicsHeader
                                FieldActivityID="111" 
                                />
                            '
                                foreach ($decode_data as $key => $value) {
                                    '<FACharacteristicsRow
                                        rowAction="Change" 
                                        FieldActivityID="111" 
                                        CharacteristicType="'.$value->type_cd.'" 
                                        Sequence="'.$value->sort_seq.'"
                                        SearchCharacteristicValue="'.$value->user_value.'" 
                                        CharacteristicValue="'.$value->user_value.'">
                                    </FACharacteristicsRow>'
                                } 
                            '
                        </FACharacteristics>
                        <FaRem>
                            <FaRemHeader
                                FieldActivityID="111" 
                                />

                        </FaRem>
                        <FaLog>
                            <FaLogHeader
                                FieldActivityID="111" 
                                />
                            <FaLogRow
                                rowAction="Add" 
                                FieldActivityID="111" 
                                Sequence="2"
                                DateTime="2018-10-06 02:50:00" 
                                Details="" 
                                User="Users2" 
                                LogType="MSG" 
                                >
                            </FaLogRow>
                        </FaLog>
                    </C1FieldActivityMaintenanceDetails>
                </C1FieldActivityMaintenanceService>
            </C1FieldActivityMaintenance>
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';

    print_r($xmlrequest);
}
```

I want to foreach the json data after decoded in xml, but when i run it in postman i got error like this :

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: syntax error, unexpected &#039;foreach&#039; (T_FOREACH)
```

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just use `foreach()` like that in the middle of a string. If you want to properly do it, do something like this:

```
public function createXml(Request $request){
    $data = $request->input('data');
    $decode_data = json_decode($data);

    $xmlrequest = '
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:c1c="http://splwg.com/C1CustomerContactMaintenance.xsd">
       <SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:wsse="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <wsse:Security>
            <wsse:UsernameToken>       
                <wsse:Username>Username</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="PasswordText">Password</wsse:Password>        
            </wsse:UsernameToken>    
        </wsse:Security>  
       </SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            <C1FieldActivityMaintenance dateTimeTagFormat="CdxDateTime"  transactionType ="UPDATE" >
                <C1FieldActivityMaintenanceService>
                    <C1FieldActivityMaintenanceHeader
                        FieldActivityID="111" 

                    /><C1FieldActivityMaintenanceDetails 
                        FieldActivityID="111" 
                        ActivityType="DE"  
                        > 
                        <FASteps>
                            <FAStepsHeader
                                FieldActivityID="111" 
                                />

                        </FASteps>
                        <FACharacteristics>
                            <FACharacteristicsHeader
                                FieldActivityID="111" 
                                />
    ';

    foreach ($decode_data as $key => $value) {
        $xmlrequest .='<FACharacteristicsRow
            rowAction="Change" 
            FieldActivityID="111" 
            CharacteristicType="'.$value->type_cd.'" 
            Sequence="'.$value->sort_seq.'"
            SearchCharacteristicValue="'.$value->user_value.'" 
            CharacteristicValue="'.$value->user_value.'">
        </FACharacteristicsRow>'
    } 

    $xmlrequest .= '
                        </FACharacteristics>
                        <FaRem>
                            <FaRemHeader
                                FieldActivityID="111" 
                                />

                        </FaRem>
                        <FaLog>
                            <FaLogHeader
                                FieldActivityID="111" 
                                />
                            <FaLogRow
                                rowAction="Add" 
                                FieldActivityID="111" 
                                Sequence="2"
                                DateTime="2018-10-06 02:50:00" 
                                Details="" 
                                User="Users2" 
                                LogType="MSG" 
                                >
                            </FaLogRow>
                        </FaLog>
                    </C1FieldActivityMaintenanceDetails>
                </C1FieldActivityMaintenanceService>
            </C1FieldActivityMaintenance>
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
    ';

    print_r($xmlrequest);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Simple answer**

You cannot use foreach in between single quotation marks. You should first create a variable then reference it in the xml.

```
$foreachResult = "";

foreach ($decode_data as $key => $value) {
    $foreachResult += <--your xml code-->;
}
```

then

```
<FACharacteristicsHeader
   FieldActivityID="111"/>' . $foreachResult . '/>
```

**Preferred way:**

It is really hard to see through and understand xml codes in php files. You can use twig to render xml in Laravel.

Example: [Rendering xml with twig in laravel](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/generate-a-sitemap-use-blade-for-xml-document) (look the best answer)